# Can not login with HybridAuth

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I installed Drupal HybridAuth module on my site for social authentication. I configured this module and it is displaying fine on site block. But when I try to login with any Social Media account details, it is processing correctly, but I cannot login in my site. How can I solve this?
Here's a link to the site:
example.com

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I would check.

- Make sure you're using the correct redirect URIs and JavaScript Origins. For example, the redirect URI should be **https://www.example.com/coupon/hybridauth/endpoint?hauth.done=Google** and the app you've registered at Google contain this too. The JavaScript Origins at Google should contain **www.example.com** (and **example.com** if you allow that too).
- Since you're running the site in a subdir, make sure you've set **RewriteBase** in **.htaccess** to **/coupon/**. That might cause a problem with redirecting after auth.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the identity to your user account:

1. Go to your user profile at user/.
2. In the "HybridAuth identities", if you don't see the authentication provider listed, you need to go through the authorization process:
3. Click on "HybridAuth" tab.
4. Under "Add more identities", click on one of the social icons provided. This will initiate the authorization process that will allow HybridAuth to log you in using that account.